# Java Vender Loop Beginner

Tags: java

There's a problem with my loops when I input the drinks, such as **water, tea, soda**.

Also, I don't want it to print the return until after the user has input the drink choice in, but that keeps showing up each time as well.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;


   public class Vending
   {

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {


       System.out.print("Enter a command = ");

       double balance = 0.0;
       String a;


    // scanner input
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (in.hasNext()) 
    {
        String command = in.nextLine();
        if (command.equals("penny")) 
        {
            balance = balance + 0.01;
            System.out.println("balance = " + balance);
        } 
        if (command.equals("nickel")) 
        {
            balance = balance + 0.05;
            System.out.println("balance = " + balance);
        } 
        if (command.equals("dime"))
          {
            balance = balance + 0.10;
            System.out.println("balance = " + balance);
        } 
         if (command.equals("quarter"))
          {
            balance = balance + 0.25;
            System.out.println("balance = " + balance);
        } 
         if (command.equals("dollar"))
          {
            balance = balance + 1.00;
            System.out.println("balance = " + balance);
        } 

        else if (command.equals("break")) 
        {
            break;
        }

        else if (command.equals("water")) 
        {
          System.out.println("Water");
            System.out.println("balance = " + balance - 1.25);
        } 
        else if (command.equals("tea")) 
        {
          System.out.println("Tea");
             System.out.println("balance = " + balance - 1.50);
        } 
        else if (command.equals("soda")) 
        {
          System.out.println("soda");
             System.out.println("balance = " + balance - 1.75);
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("return " + balance + " to customer");
        }

        balance++;
    }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you didn't start using **`else if`** straight away. You should be using this after the first use of **`if`**.

It starts at the first if, checks it, and then moves to the next if. When you get to the part where it checks for `dollar` it will only check the others if you `dollar` was false. This is because they are `else if`.

So if you input `dime` for example, it will add 0.10 and then check for quarter, and then dollar. Then it enters the `else if` block. It then checks for break, water, tea, etc and then finds all are false.(you put in dime) and then hits the else block printing the balance.

So to fix this overall you should be using separate methods to check for a money value or an item.

Answer (score 0):

in Java 7 switch statement support "String" value, try to change your code like this:

```
String command = in.nextLine();
switch(command) {
     case "penny": 
             //do something
             break;
     case "water": 
             //do something
             break;
     case "tea": 
             //do something
             break;
     case "soda": 
             //do something
             break;
     default: 
             System.out.println("return " + balance + " to customer");
}
balance++;
```

Hope this help your issue.

Comment: Yeah I would recommend this too if you are using Java 7. But there are still other errors in the op's code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I can see a couple of issues here

1. instead of in.nextLine(), rather use in.next(), this will read the input on the first "enter"
2. if you want the return printout to be printed at the end, move it out of the loop so that once the user finished by entering "break" it will then print out the return bit.
3. you never decrease the balance with the price of the item... Instead of the balance++;. Change it to balance -= price; (balance = balance - price;)

   ```
   while (in.hasNext()) {
       String command = in.next();
                   double price = 0.0;
                    ...
                    ...
       else if (command.equals("water")) {
           System.out.println("Water");
           price = 1.25;
       } else if (command.equals("tea")) {
           System.out.println("Tea");
           price = 1.50;
       } else if (command.equals("soda")) {
           System.out.println("soda");
           price =1.75;
       }

       balance -= price;
                   System.out.println("balance is " + balance);
   }
   System.out.println("return " + balance + " to customer");
   ```